# Find existing PushbuttonField in PDF document using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrobat, pdf-form

I am using the Java iText library to manipulate form fields of a PDF document and have run into a simple problem.  I am able to set properties of AcroFields that I retrieved from a PdfStamper object however what I really want to do is set an Action to an existing push button field.

I have found countless examples of creating a new PushButton field and adding it to a document, however none that actually retrieve an existing PushbuttonField object.  I am sure that is the correct object because it has a setAction method where the AcroField object does not.

I am willing to accept that it is impossible because I could work around this by using Acrobat to remove the button from the template and then programatically adding it fresh everytime.

Further I would like to know if anybody knows of a more comprehensive location for documentation on iText.  Incomplete javadocs and specific code examples don't make for the best documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the name of the pushbuttonfield to retrieve it. Take a look at [the example](http://www.itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=156) to see how to retrieve, adjust and replace.

You can set actions if you have the PushbuttonField#getField()#setAction()

Comment: Took 5 minutes to figure out the above with the *incomplete javadocs and specific code examples*

Comment: Wow... how did I miss this?!  I am just going to bite the bullet and buy the iText in Action manual.  I am terrible at finding free documentation for iText.

Comment: You can also add a PdfAction using the low-level `PdfDictionary.put()` method.  But for that, you need to know the [Pdf Spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) pretty well.

Comment: Get all field names in a pdf from PdfStamper.AcroFields.Fields